# return mysql thread_id

Tags: java, mysql

Whenever I connect to mysql using command prompt, It returns a thread_id (**64** in this case).
Is it possible to get this number using Java (preferred) or PHP?

```
# mysql -h10.10.10.10 -uroot -proot@123
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 64
Server version: 5.0.77-log Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.
```

Comment: **Query**: `SELECT CONNECTION_ID();`

Comment: Is it possible to know from which server does the connection happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CONNECTION_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) function will help you.

**Query**:

`SELECT CONNECTION_ID();`